# Values For Parameters In SSRS

Tags: date, visual-studio-2012, parameters, expression, ssrs-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

I have created two parameters, StartDate and EndDate, which are both Date/Time parameters.

In my EndDate parameter, I have set the Default Value to `Today()` in order to get today's date.

For my StartDate parameter, I want it to be based off the EndDate parameter in the following way. Whatever date the user selects as End Date, StartDate will be the date 24 months/2 years prior. (For example, if EndDate was Today (1/11/2017)...then StartDate would be 1/11/2015.)

In the expressions box, this is what I have so far for my default value for StartDate.     `=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-2,Today())`

How do I get it, so that every time I change the EndDate, the StartDate updates accordingly to be 2 years prior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression it will return 1/22/2015

```
=Date.Now.Date.AddYears(-2).AddDays(10)
```

Comment: This expression works...but how is it triggered by the End Date? Do I have to create a cascading parameter or something?

Comment: I figured it out from your initial answer, so I thank you.